# swTPM vs. Hardware TPM: Are there any security downsides?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, tpm, libvirt

**Backstory:**

For a while, I've been wanting to install my next Windows PC as a VM on a Linux platform to allow me to re-image my machine when I loose a disk or Windows poops itself* (I'm thinking Clear Linux, despite me being a CentOS person).

(*The current Win10 install has just begun signs of said pooping. It's been daily dev / gaming machine / Linux VM host for 7 years.)

Enter the Windows 11 + TPM 2.0 discussion.

I've been playing with this & researching trying to work out if a TPM pass-through available or even logically possible. At this point I'm thinking the answer is no, as the TPM would be required to support two machines concurrently. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

**The *actual* questions**

1. Is a virtual TPM cryptographically equivalent to the motherboards hardware one?
2. Are there any security concerns with swTPM or other virtual TPMs?
3. (Generically) Does anyone see any problem with the Linux Host -> Windows VM model for a developer + gamer?
4. Bonus Question: If the Linux host OS is using TPM, does the Windows client inherently benefit from that without explicitly implementing TPM functions?

In case you're astute enough to note the above Windows -> Linux VM reference, there's every chance I may want to run a VM-ception (Clear Linux -> Windows 11 -> Another VM).

Planned specs have this as about i5-11600, 32GB Ram, RTX 3060, probably Z*** motherboard. (Although the B*** Boards don't look too bad this time around.)

-- EDIT --

Added 4th question. According to a very brief Googling, it seems that at least Arch implements TPM by default.

Comment: Parallels have a software TPM so you can get Win11 on Intel Mac, thereby locking it to that physical computer, perhaps other VMs may follow suit. idk much about how it works, only that it exists - https://kb.parallels.com/en/122702

Comment: vTPM features do exist in other virtualization software (VMware, Hyper-V, Qemu), the main question is whether they provide any meaningful security against someone who copies the VM-related files to a different host, and maybe also against someone who is able to monitor/debug the hypervisor itself. (It seems that Parallels achieves the former, but Qemu with swTPM does not.)

Comment: It’s also unnecessary. TPM 2.0 and Secure Boot is not required to run Windows 11 within a VM.

Comment: @user1686 - that's what I was wondering, yes. Presuming that hypervisor monitoring/debugging is out of scope, does the vTPM actually protect - as opposed to just "tick" the box for Win11?

Comment: @Ramhound - necessity is not in question here.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have been pondering your response. Do you mean that the role of security (requiring the TPM) is handled entirely by the host OS, and thus the guest OS doesn't require it from a security stand point? OR do you mean that you can get by without Windows accessing the TMP in general?